# What is the correct way to deal with "Logging In" for an app written against RESTful web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, uri

I am in the process of building a RESTful API for my application.  There are very few services that are public and the rest require authentication and authorization.

To be clear, my question is NOT about authenticating web services.  I have already decided to send an HTTP header with an access token provided by the server.  The reasons for this include:

- Creating a "session" that can track the user activity
- Timeout access tokens after XXX amount of inactivity
- Track user behavior patterns for each "session"

So far, this approach is working fine.  I am interested in any design guidelines for providing a "Login" service.  I don't want to just authenticate a request, but I want to track usage of the web service against a "session".

In addition to "session" tracking, we have requirements that require that we track failed login attempts and take appropriate action after XXX number of failed attempts as well as password expiring and email address verification before authorizing, etc.

Specifically, I am concerned with the best way to design the URI's for this.  One option would be:

```
/api/authentication/login?username=UN&password=PW
```

That could return the access token to be used in the header for secure service calls.  Is this a good approach?  Is there a better approach?  Is there a better patter to use for naming the URI?

My biggest problem is that the URI is not purely sticking with the "URI's should represent resources" approach.  End the end it is probably not a big deal, but I am wondering if there are better ways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Often, RESTful APIs like to be stateless. That means that the API itself doesn't care about keeping a session, and doesn't.

What you do is authenticate 1 time, and then get a temporary key. That key eventually is no good anymore because the key has information in it about when it will expire.

Also, since these large APIs are built on message queues, they know timestamps for each action. and they can basically keep track of activity.

So, in RESTful API design, you often have scenarios where your URL has resources in it, and then there are all sorts of additional things that need to be set.

A good rule of thumb is to *hide the complexity behind your `?`*. A typical use case of this *philosophy* is where you have a bunch of filter options on a get request of `/some/resource`. How is this relevant? Well, if you remember that its not a mortal sin to decorate your resource based API with other stuff occassionally, then you can treat other scenarios similarly when you feel like resourcefulness may be in question, but essentially you still have RPC-ish endpoints that need to exist to make your API fully functional for your needs. Or, of course, you can just arbitrarily set certain HTTP verbs to equal those things.

If you want to extend your resources with additional functionality, try to stick to the resource structure in your base url of the call, and then *decorate* it with your one-off needs.

```
Resource: /api/authentication
With modifier: /api/authentication/login
With data: /api/authentication/login?username=UN&password=PW
```

Its not so bad. But again, if you wanted to go completely restful, you could say something like this (this is pure conjecture, you need to decide these things for yourself):

```
Get logged in status - GET - /api/authentication/:id
Create / Update logged in status - POST / PUT - /api/authentication(/:id)
Log out - DELETE - /api/authentication/:id
```

... or you could have omitted the `:id` route and just *hid* that information in the body of data appended to the call, aka *hiding complexity*

Comment: Yes, I would describe what I am doing to be very similar to what you have described.  If you notice, my question is more about design of the URI.  I know it might seem trivial, but I haven't found anyone else talking about this and I am curious as to what others think.

Comment: ah, the emphasis on that part was not clear in your question. see my updated answer.

Comment: I tend to like your second approach.  My issue is whether or not to be more explicit to the user of the API that they are "logging in".  The reason being that many failed attempts would lock the account as well as other login rules that will be applied.  Good idea though.  I think I will probably use something very similar to this unless someone else chimes in with something that seems better :)

Comment: truthfully, there is no better or worse... its just a matter of what you need for your needs. you're just gonna have to weigh it all out and decide works best for your application.